# iOS node not syncing with private BKC

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, synchronization, ios

I use the Geth framework and Swift 4 to boot a node inside an iOS 11.0 app. This node connects to my local BKC (to 4 nodes to be precise).

Here are some tests I made :

- if I start 3 computer nodes and start mining, the 4th computer node will sync on start
- if I start all my nodes (computer and app) and start mining on a computer node, each node will notice it and sync
- if I start all my computer nodes and start mining and then I boot a fresh new app node, the app node won't sync (even if he connects without any issue to computer nodes)
- if I start my app node with Rinkeby genesis and bootnodes, it will sync after a few seconds

So, I probably missed something but I don't understand why my app node syncs with Rinkeby and not with my private blockchain.

I'm using a static-nodes.json file to connect all my nodes together (computer and app).

I start my computer nodes with : 
`geth --datadir <datadir> --port <port> --networkid <id> --v5disc --lightserv <int> console`.

I use a custom genesis file. The `admin.peers` method confirms me that all my nodes connect to each other without any issue. And I use the `GethSetVerbosity(9)` to display trace and debug in my Xcode console.

Any idea ?

Comment: If you’re still having this issue, it would be awesome if you could edit your question and provide your network topology and opened ports between the nodes and the IOS device. If you’ve solved the issue, it would be awesome if you could “self answer” too!

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to use an iOS device as a node? I can't think a reason for doing that. For most things that you'll need in a mobile you could do with [JSON RCP](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC).